# How to grep line with string if found on every 3rd line if not on next line

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to grep the lines with pattern "01" if found for each letter, if not grep "02", if not grep "03".

```
$ sed -n '/01/p' file1 > file2
```

The file1 is like

```
a01
a02
a03
k01
k02
k03
m02
m03
l01
l03
y03
c02
c03
```

Expected result in file2 like

```
a01
k01
m02
l01
y03
c02
```

Comment: I think your question benefits if you tell us what you have tried. (It is generally expected of you to try as hard as possible to solve your problem on your own.) There is more useful tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is the input sorted so that the lowest number will always be first for each letter?

Comment: Yes the input is sorted

Comment: I have tried $ sed -n '1~3p' file1 >file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This magic incantation will print the line where the first character is seen for the first time:

```
awk '!seen[substr($1,1,1)]++' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I got it. I added a 1st character value as prefix to the line and made my file1 as:aaa a01
aaa a02
aaa a03
kkk k01
kkk k02
kkk k03
mmm m02
mmm m03
lll l01
lll l03
yyy y03
ccc c02
ccc c03
Now, I run $ awk '!seen[substr($1,1,1)]++' file1.txt > file2.txt and run $ cat file2.txt
aaa a01
kkk k01
mmm m02
lll l01
yyy y03
ccc c02
Then I run $ cut -d' ' -f2 file2.txt > file3.txt and $ cat file3.txt
a01
k01
m02
l01
y03
c02

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I tried using $ awk '!seen[substr($1,1,2)]++' file and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Glenn I have another question on this thread: I have like a list of nodes, i.e. zkgm1bdbng02.kgm1b.cci.att.com
zkgm1bdbng03.kgm1b.cci.att.com
zlsa1adbng02.lsa1a.cci.att.com
zlsa1adbng03.lsa1a.cci.att.com
zlsa1aglma03.lsa1a.cci.att.com
zlsa1alcma01.lsa1a.cci.att.com
zlsa1alcma02.lsa1a.cci.att.com
zlsa1bdbng02.lsa1b.cci.att.com
zlsa1bdbng03.lsa1b.cci.att.com
zlsa1bglma01.lsa1b.cci.att.com
zlsa1bglma03.lsa1b.cci.att.com Now I like to pick only 01 nodes (zlsa1bglma01) from the list, if not 02 and if not 03... How do I twick this awk command to pick the right nodes..

Comment: So here 01 nodes from each domain i.e lsa1b for example used above as node zlsa1bglma01

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I ran awk '!seen[substr($1,1,9)]++' and now I can collect node for each domain with unique of 01/02/03. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sort <file1> | uniq -w 1
```

This will compare only the first letter in the input file. Let me know if this works out. Assuming you file is a sorted one.